# Сделать выборку колонок из DataGridViev

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, linq2sql

Очень нужна помощь в задании. Есть на форме `DataGridView`, в которую считываются данные из базы данных.
Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь мог выбрать нужные ему колонки и они выводились вместо изначальной таблицы.
Привожу скрин изначальной формы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
База данных присоединена с помощью `DataSet`, есть файл класса LINQ to SQL.
Строка подключения

```
public static  linqWorkDataContext db = new linqWorkDataContext();
```

Пробую такой запрос :

```
Table<Registr> reg = db.GetTable<Registr>();
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    var sumEl = (from s in db.GetTable<Registr>() select s.quantity);
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (var item in sumEl) { sum =+ (int)item; }
    // int sum = sumEl.Sum(n => n.quantity);    
    var amountEl = (from a in db.GetTable<Registr>() select a.amount);
    decimal amount = 0;
    foreach (var i in amountEl) amount =+(decimal)i);
    var v = (from r in db.GetTable<Registr>() select new { r.date, sum, amount }).Distinct();
    registrDataGridView.DataSource = v;
}
```

Он, можно сказать, не работает. Его результат прилагаю в скрине: [image: результат]
Вот такой результат при запросе

```
            var v = (from r in reg
                     select new
                     {
                         Company = checkBox2.Checked ? r.company : null,
                         Sum = checkBox6.Checked ? (from s in reg select s.quantity).Sum() : null,
                         Amount = checkBox7.Checked ? (from a in reg select a.amount).Sum() : null
                         // аналогично остальные свойства
                     }) registrDataGridView.DataSource = v;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, нужно убрать все пустые колонки и вывести только те, что выбраны. 
На последнем скриншоте показано, что колонки остаются пустыми,их нужно убрать совсем.

Comment: Так в чём вопрос-то? Как сделать грид с чекбоксами в хедере? И вообще, дайте больше информации: какая технология используется для работы с БД: сырой ADO.NET, EF или другая ORM? Как данные попадают в грид: ручной маппинг, привязка?

Comment: Уточнила. Если все еще мало информации,спрашивайте. Только помогите , пожалуйста :(

Comment: Колонки в датагриде автогенерируемые? Или есть вручную добавленные?

Comment: Все автогенерируемые

Comment: Что-то тут не то. В запросе `Company` и `Amount` с большой буквы, на скриншоте - с маленькой, `Sum` вообще отсутствует. Похоже, к гриду что-то другое привязано.

Comment: В базе данных все колонки с маленькой буквы. 
Почему  в своем запросе вы писали Company и т.д. с большой? 
Только что в коде поменяла все на маленькие - результат аналогичный.
 sum -такого поля нет. Есть quantuty ,по которому мне нужна сумма

Comment: При привязке данных названия колонок будут взяты из привязанной коллекции. Они **должны** быть с большой. Уберите **все** `if (checkBoxN.Checked)` из кода.

Comment: Хорошо.Попробую.
Как же все-таки выводить только те поля,которые указывает пользователь?
 Мне задание нужно решить до конца сегодняшнего дня. Я сейчас в дороге,потом попробую еще что-то поменять. Сможете ли вы мне помочь немного позже?

Comment: Ну что там, подвижки есть?

Comment: Сделала с помощью Entity Framework , все что надо получилось,кроме одного: нет возможности выбрать несколько полей .

Comment: Этот вопрос тоже надо решить,буду делать новый вопрос сейчас...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, нужно выбирать только определённые колонки. Самым простым способом, пожалуй, будет следующий:

```
var v = (from r in reg
         select new
         {
             Date = DateCheckBox.Checked ? r.date : null,
             Sum = SumCheckBox.Checked ? (from s in reg select s.quantity).Sum() : null,
             Amount = AmountCheckBox.Checked ? (from a in reg select a.amount).Sum() : null
             // аналогично остальные свойства
         })
         .Distinct();
```

Это приведёт к тому, что вместо ненужных значений везде будут `null`. В `DataGridView` в итоге будет пусто на их месте. Всё как на скриншоте.

Альтернативой будет применение Dynamic Linq. Это позволит более гибко составлять запрос, вообще убирая ненужные колонки, но существенно сложнее для старта.

---

И, кстати, не делайте `DataContext` статическим полем. Если в процессе работы произойдёт исключение или просто истечёт таймаут на соединение, то контекст далее станет невозможно использовать.

Рекомендуемой практикой является создание контекста каждый раз, как происходит обращение к БД. Обязательно вызывайте `Dispose`, а лучше используйте `using`.

Не стоит волноваться об эффективности: соединение с БД будет установлено при первом обращении и сохранено в пуле соединений. Если что-то произойдёт (истечёт таймаут), то проблем не возникнет: при новом создании контекста будет установлено новое соединение.

Comment: Так же как и в моем запросе, в вашем сумму и количество не считает - пустые поля. Вы совершенно правы,мне нужно,чтоб остальные колонки пропадали. Над этим и мучаюсь уже не один день. Работает с чекбоксами сумма : 
 var sumEl = (from s in db.GetTable<Registr>() select s.quantity).Sum();var amountEl = (from a in db.GetTable<Registr>() select a.amount).Sum();
textBox1.Text = amountEl.ToString();
textBox2.Text = sumEl.ToString();
var v = (from r in db.GetTable<Registr>() select new { r.company}).Distinct();
Хотя в задании требуется не так...
Теперь нужно ,чтобы выводились конкретные поля

Comment: @SoftySh - у меня в тестовом примере всё работает. Проверяйте чекбоксы.

Comment: Вы говорили, что можно использовать Dynamic Linq для выборки только определенных таблиц.Подскажите пожалуйста,как это можно сделать? Уж очень нужна помощь.

Comment: Я вижу, что многие даты одинаковые. Попробуйте убрать `Distinct()` из запроса. Что выводится в этом случае?

Comment: Привела скриншот сверху в задании

Comment: Приведенный вами запрос работает, но почему-то считает все данные ,которые есть в таблице , а не для конкретно выбранного поля.

Comment: @SoftySh - Я просто скопировал ваш подзапрос. Нужно делать группировку по выбранному полю.

Comment: Примерно так?  Company = checkBox2.Checked ? (from s in reg group s by s.company into g select g.company) : null,

Comment: @SoftySh - Примерно так. Но комментарии не предназначены для дискуссии. Создавайте новый вопрос. И, да, я видел ваш сегодняшний вопрос. Появится время - посмотрю.

Comment: Задам уже последний вопрос в этой теме,пока вы не ушли : в запросе с группировкой ругается на g.company "Не содержит определения для 'company' и метод расширения,принимающий первый аргумент для типа IGrouping<string,Registr>. Из-за чего это?

Comment: Alexander Petrov, посмотрите ,я создала новый вопрос ,где делаю вариант с приведенным вами кодом.  Пожалуйста .https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661186/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-datagridview?noredirect=1#comment953222_661186