# Выбрать несколько полей в combocheckbox

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Здравствуйте. Очень нужна ваша помощь.
Есть приложение на winform, связанное с базой данных. С помощью Entity Framework выводится таблица (на datagridwiew), есть combocheckbox, в котором можно выбрать поля. Пользователь выбирает поле и по этому полю выводится общее количество, общая сумма и само выбранное поле. Привожу скрин,чтоб было понятнее, как все работает. Выборка осуществляется с помощью linq, например:

```
if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == "date")
            {
                var query = from order in ct.Registration.ToList()
                group order by order.date into g
                select new
                {
                    Date = g.Key,
                    Quantity = g.Sum(order => order.quantity),
                    Amount= g.Sum(order => order.amount)
                };
                dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }
```

Задача стоит вот в чем: нужно реализовать возможность выбрать несколько полей. На втором скрине показано, что выбрано поле date. А нужно, чтобы можно было выбрать, например date и company. Как это можно сделать? Возможно ли это реализовать, если используется Entity Framework? 
Так же желательно не использовать combocheckbox, а просто поставить чекбоксы на каждой колонке(чтобы не привязывать колонку к ее названию)
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишите:

> `var query = from order in ct.Registration.ToList()`...

Это читается как "вытяни все данные из таблицы `Registration`...". Вы приводите [`IQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx) к [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx). Это не нужно (зачем?). Это нужно будет после построения выборки.

Итого получаем:

```
var registrations = ct.Registration.OrderBy(r => r.date).ToList()
```

Далее.

Не уверен, что вам надо при каждом показе/скрытии колонки ползти в базу. Достаточно будет просто при инициализации загрузить данные и после изменять видимость колонок у `DataGridView` контрола.

Вы можете использовать [`CheckedListBox.CheckedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx). Но к данной задаче это не совсем подходит, ибо мы можем скрыть колонки, не включенные в этот `CheckedListBox` (`quantity`, например). Поэтому можно поступить так:

```
foreach (var column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    var item = checkedListBox1.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Text == colunm.Name);
    if (item != null)
    {
        column.Visible = item.Selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: var query = from order in ct.Registration.ToList()
Это нужно,чтобы изначально заполнялась вся  таблица и была видна пользователю.(чтобы он посмотрел и решил,чтоб ему выбирать)

На FirstOrDefault и Visibility ругается студия

Comment: Я сейчас больше склоняюсь к варианту с чекбоксами на каждой колонке. Но для этого Entity framework использовать не получится...

Comment: @SoftySh ошибся, поправил `Visibility` на `Visible`. Для [`Linq.FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) подключите `System.Linq` библиотеку.

Comment: Поменяла, все равно подчеркивает.

Comment: Если вам не будет тяжело,посмотрите пожалуйста мой вариант с checkbox ( вместо entity framework используется класс linq to sql)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658712/%D0%A1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-datagridviev/658861#658861

Comment: Может быть , в таком варианте легче будет выбирать нужные колонки?

Comment: @SoftySh странно выглядит это... Колонка не скрыта, она есть, а значений в ней нет, если чекбокс не отмечен. Вам не кажется, что это бесполезная функциональность?

Comment: Кажется.
Мне это и нужно,чтобы пустые в итоге пропадали,если они не отмечены.

Comment: Пропадали? А как тогда можно будет отметить чекбокс, чтобы они появились тогда?

Comment: Сделать кнопку, которая будет возвращать всю таблицу в ее первоначальном виде.

Comment: А вам не кажется, что в текущем виде программа более user-friendly?

Comment: Это так и есть. Но ее нужно сделать более универсальной: 1) чтоб была возможность выбрать несколько полей; 2) независимость от названий колонок(полей); 3)к тому же,нужно учесть,что что полный набор полей таблицы с данными может быть заранее неизвестен и определяется в результате запроса(это вообще для меня за гранью возможного)